# Modulo behaviour with if statement in C++

Tags: c++

Why this code returning 5. First if is returning 5%2 = 1 and if false on if(1). why is so.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int fn_test(int i=5)
{
    if(i%2) return i++;
    else
    return fn_test(i-1);
}
int main()
{ int test=fn_test(5);
   cout<< " this is out put " << test;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Modulo give you the remainder of a integer division, so what did you expect actually?

Comment: BTW, you may simplify your example by removing recursive call, `++`, and default argument.

Comment: @Hassan `5%2` yields `1`, so its equivalent to `true`. Any numeric value besides `0` will be converted to `true`.

Comment: Just posted the same question which was asked in interview :) sorry for extra lines :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thats not happening in this code. if(5%2) returns me false. thats my exact question.

Comment: @Hassan _"returns me false"_ [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/374afcd85e1736e3) sorry.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks for your time it was returning me true and i was not clear about return i++; this will return me 5 because i++ will be lost. Thanks again much appreciated.

Comment: @Hassan The right tool to solve such problems is to use your debugger, but not to ask at Stack Overflow before you did so. Tell us all your observations you made when inspecting your code stepping through line by line in 1st place. Also you might want to read [**How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**]  At least leave us with a **[MCVE]** that reproduces your problem. (This is a personal stock comment provided by πάντα ῥεῖ™)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `5%2` is `1` as you notice, which is non-zero and therefore "true". Only zero is "false", everything else is "true".

That means you do `return i++`, which returns the *old* value of `i` (i.e. `5`) before incrementing `i`.

Comment: In my case old value was 5 then return i++ should return me 6 that is not happening in this code.

Comment: @Hassan No, the result of `i++` is the *old* value, in your example `5`.That is the value that `return` will return. The increment is lost. If you had `++i` *then* the result would be `6`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications yes you are right it will return me pre incremental value.

Comment: @Hassan - since `i` goes away at the end of the function, there's no point in incrementing it. Returning `i + 1` is sufficient.